# is it ok to use the new LLMFunction in answering questions on this site?

Tags: discussion

I've just used the new [LLMFunction](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/05/the-new-world-of-llm-functions-integrating-llm-technology-into-the-wolfram-language/)  (which will be part of 13.3) to [answer a question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285572/split-string-at-first-space/285573#285573) here.

I assumed this is ok since this is part of Mathematica (now as Paclet, but soon builtin) but wanted to make sure.

Is it OK to use Wolfram `LLMFunction` in answering Mathematica questions on this forum? If this is not allowed, will delete my answer.

Comment: I mean this is fundamentally a different use case than just typing stuff into ChatGPT and doesn't feel that different than using the other ML stuff in the language so I'd say go for it

Comment: Personally, I would probably downvote an answer that contained _only_ a solution with the use of `LLMFunction` because such an answer is not really an answer on how to solve a problem in Mathematica but how to "solve" it with OpenAI LLM (note that `LLMFunction` is just a wrapper for calling GPT). Moreover, such solutions are probably not going to be very robust – or at least will be less robust than a proper Mathematica solution.

Comment: How did you handle the authentication? I could see a default Authentication->Automatic but no indication of the syntax for providing the api key. Just using the key from OpenAI didn't work for me

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I logged into openAI, went to my account settings, then clicked on "generate key". Then copied the key and pasted it into the pop-up menu which Mathematica had opened and waiting for the key to be typed in. Then clicked accept and done. That is all.  As Wolfram blog says, you need a key to use. I think this is something that needs to be done each time per session., I do not think the key is saved after exiting Mathematica.

Comment: @Nasser I already had the openAI key but I never got a popup asking me to enter the key. Therefore assumed it had to be entered as an option. I'm on 13.2 and using the paclet install version of LLMFunction(s)

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I think this is the problem. There is a pop-up menu you get first time  after you issue the **first** LLMFunction call.  The pop-up menu do not show up otherwise. I think this is bad design. But maybe they will fix this in 13.3. After I issued first command, I got an error message and large pop-up window came up asking me to type in a key.  I am using 13.2.1 on windows 10.  I think documentation should really explain all this to users with screen shots and step-by-step.

Comment: For the answer to be functional, a user must register with openAI....In other words, the solution is not available free to all users of Mathematica. I suppose it's the same as using MATLink to call Matlab to provide a solution to a problem, though the Matlab hurdle is a bit higher. I wrote an answer recently that called GAP to do some group theory calculation that Mma couldn't do. Didn't get many votes, of course. And we've got an acegen subcommunity on site. Each of these is slightly different I suppose. Be hard to find a good reason to ban any of them. Except W|A, of course.

Comment: @MichaelE2 registration at openAI is free. actually I just used my google account to login to openAI (they have an option to do this). So anyone can have free account at openAI (like one can have free account at Yahoo or Google). So it is free. But I agree that I do not like having to make an account somewhere to use a Wolfram function. May be in V 13.3 they will make it so one does not have to do this. (i.,e use it without a key).

Comment: Since Wolfram seems to be so much into AI and LLM from his videos and writings, he is now integrating all of this into Wolfram language. In few versions I can see half of Wolfram language functions depending on use of this new technology. It will be hard to say which one is allowed to use here and which function one is not allowed to use. This function is for me the same as using any other Wolfram function which uses curated data from other external sources.  The picture is soon going to be fuzzy, which function uses or does not use external sources to obtain the answer when using Mathematica.

Comment: For the specific case in question, I agree with @Domen. I think if the only suggestion provided was to use LLMFunction, then that would be a disservice to the person asking the question. Especially if their actual goal was to process a large batch of data. I haven't tried LLVMFunction yet, but I can imagine that latencies would make it untenable in a batch situation. Also, if I'm understanding your post correctly, the result of calling LLMFunction wasn't in a Mathematica-native format (as in more structure than a string), so it's significantly less helpful than a "native" solution.

Comment: @ Nasser, I mean "registration at openAI" is itself a barrier, a *constraint*, not free. At least when I tried it, they wanted me *to give them* my phone number. That's not free. I don't equate "no fee" with "free". Neither does OpenAI, I suspect, whatever they pretend.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree with you, it is a hassle to get openAI account and key. At first I tried to sign in using my email, but never got verification email back to activate it. emailed openAI support, never got a response. Then by chance I found I can login to openAI using my google account (which I do not like to use). I think Wolfram should fix all this for V 13.3 so that people do not have to depend on getting accounts at external sites just to use Wolfram builtin functions. fyi, I deleted the two answers I had using LLMFunction and will not use it again to answer any questions.

Comment: @Nasser I don't think it's a problem that people need accounts with external services to use WL functions that explicitly depend on those services. There are other examples of this already in the language. Also, I wasn't advocating that you delete your answers, just that they don't have the appearance of canonical answers that take precedence over "native" answers (and if I recall, you weren't doing that).

Comment: @ Nasser, I thought the general gist of my comment was meant to convey it was okay to post LLM solutions. I figure most solutions won't be as good as WL solutions except in their simplicity.  I think sometimes, one might be able to solve problems with it that are difficult or impossible to figure out in WL -- won't know that until it happens.  In any case, my attitude is to be open to its as yet unknown possibilities. If it ever gives a bad solution, theoretically the up/downvote model of SE takes care of its relative value.

Comment: Am I the only one who has found WL answers from ChatGTP to be very convincing and also full of lies? I once got a nice solution that used a Wolfram Function Repository function that does not exist. It even gave me link to the documentation (broken off course). I am OK with answers where you use AI for the initial draft of an answer, but then I think that there most be human work on top of it to validate and improve it.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I think that's a whole other topic beyond this thread...must...reisist...urge...to...discuss...